# Angular setValidity() set the different value than was setted

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have faced with the unclear situation when I try to setValidity() inside my own directive. 
It set opposite value than expression when, expression return false, and undefined when returned return true. 
So **my Angular code**:

```
<script>
        var userForm = angular.module("userForm", []);

        userForm.directive('isEquals', function () {
        return {
            // element must have ng-model attribute.
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
            otherFieldValue: "=isEquals"
            },
            link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.isEquals = function (modelValue) {
                console.log("otherFieldValue: " + scope.otherFieldValue);
                console.log("modelValue: " + modelValue);
                valid = (modelValue === scope.otherFieldValue);
                ctrl.$setValidity('isEquals', valid);
                console.log("valid: " + valid);
                //Q1: is it in fact userForm.confirmPassword.$error.isEquals?
                console.log("isEquals: " + ctrl.$error.isEquals);
                console.log("modelValue: " + modelValue);
                console.log("");
                return modelValue;
            };
            scope.$watch("otherFieldValue", function () {
                ctrl.$validate();
            });
            }
        };
        });
            userForm.controller("userFormController", function ($scope, $http) {
        });
</script>
```

and my **html code**:

```
<div  ng-app="userForm">
    <form name="userForm" modelAttribute="userForm" ng-controller="userFormController"  ng-submit="createUser()" novalidate>
        <div class="row">
            <input id="password" name="password" path="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" minlength="5" maxlength="60" ng-model="user.password" required/>
            <br>
            <span ng-show="userForm.password.$dirty && userForm.password.$error.required">Password field is required.<br></span>
            <span ng-show="userForm.password.$dirty && userForm.password.$error.minlength || userForm.password.$error.maxlength">Password field must have size from 5 to 60 symbols.<br></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" path="confirmPassword" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" minlength="5" maxlength="60" ng-model="user.confirmPassword" equals-to="user.password" required/>
            <br>
            <span ng-show="userForm.confirmPassword.$dirty && userForm.confirmPassword.$error.required">Confirm Password field is required.<br></span>
            <span ng-show="userForm.confirmPassword.$dirty && userForm.confirmPassword.$error.minlength || userForm.confirmPassword.$error.maxlength">Confirm Password field must have size from 5 to 60 symbols.<br></span>
            <span id="m1" ng-show="userForm.confirmPassword.$dirty && !userForm.confirmPassword.$error.equalsTo">Passwords are not same.<br></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input id="submit" type="submit" ng-submit="createUser()" value="Sign Up"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

But when I enter passwords i have the next situations (I will sign "Passwords are not same." AS m1) :

```
//1) valid!=equalsTo, m1 visible. Have to be valid===equalsTo===false, m1 visible.
otherFieldValue: teste
modelValue: undefined
valid: false
equalsTo: true
modelValue: undefined
//2) valid!=equalsTo, equalsTo undefined. Have to be valid===equalsTo===true. m1 still visible, but has not to be. 
otherFieldValue: teste
modelValue: teste
valid: true
equalsTo: undefined
modelValue: teste
```

I will appreciate any help, propositions, link and especially explanations. Thanks in advance.

***EDIT:*** OK. Accidentally, I figured out that it is because the directive's name and ctrl.$validators.isEquals have the same names. What is the problem with that, can someone explain?